UnknownElementException [Error]: Nest could not find DataSource element (this provider does not exis
I am writing an e2e test, the application has type or postgres 2 databases in the configuration, the test is successful, all actions with the database are performed, but when the application is closed, an error pops out of the header.
database.module
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot(),
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      inject: [ConfigService],
      name: 'adminpanel',
      useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        type: 'postgres',
        host: configService.get('ADMINPANEL_DB_HOST'),
        port: configService.get('ADMINPANEL_DB_PORT'),
        username: configService.get('ADMINPANEL_DB_USERNAME'),
        password: configService.get('ADMINPANEL_DB_PASSWORD'),
        database: configService.get('ADMINPANEL_DB_NAME'),
        entities: [__dirname + '/../modules/adminpanel/entities/*.entity.js'],
        synchronize: true,
        autoLoadEntities: true,
        // logging: true,
      }),
    }),
    2db...
  ],
  providers: [],
  exports: [TypeOrmModule],
})
export class DataBaseModule {}

e2e test
beforeAll:
dataSource = moduleFixture.get<DataSource>(
      getDataSourceToken('adminpanel'),
    );

afterAll:
if (dataSource.isInitialized) {
      await dataSource.destroy();
    }
    try {
      await app.close();
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }

dataSource.IsInitialized == true, which causes problems with understanding what to do (
I tried to export the dataSource from database.module in different ways, but this caused even more problems and the connection with the database disappeared, I also tried to make the dataSource the provider of the AppModule and the e2e test itself

I found a solution to my problem.
I have database.module and typeorm initialization:
TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
  imports: [ConfigModule],
  inject: [ConfigService],
  name: 'adminpanel',
  useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => ({
    type: 'postgres',
    host: configService.get('ADMINPANEL_DB_HOST'),
    port: configService.get('ADMINPANEL_DB_PORT'),
    username: configService.get('ADMINPANEL_DB_USERNAME'),
    password: configService.get('ADMINPANEL_DB_PASSWORD'),
    database: configService.get('ADMINPANEL_DB_NAME'),
    entities: [__dirname + '/../modules/adminpanel/entities/*.entity.js'],
    synchronize: true,
    autoLoadEntities: true,
    // logging: true,
  }),
}),

It was necessary to add a second name: 'adminpanel';
but already inside the useFactory.
It turned out the following:
TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      inject: [ConfigService],
      name: 'adminpanel',
      useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        name: 'adminpanel',
        type: 'postgres',
        host: configService.get('ADMINPANEL_DB_HOST'),
        port: configService.get('ADMINPANEL_DB_PORT'),
        username: configService.get('ADMINPANEL_DB_USERNAME'),
        password: configService.get('ADMINPANEL_DB_PASSWORD'),
        database: configService.get('ADMINPANEL_DB_NAME'),
        entities: [__dirname + '/../modules/adminpanel/entities/*.entity.js'],
        synchronize: true,
        autoLoadEntities: true,
        // logging: true,
      }),
    }),

Everything is working fine now )

The following helped in the solution:
https://github.com/nestjs/typeorm/issues/1556?ysclid=m05pzi5z5o370185268
